# Why does the elements inside my div container disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

I have a question about browser behavior when handling the elements inside of a div container. I have an Iframe that I use to make requests to the server to run PHP files, while the parent page remains dynamic. Requests made by the parent page to the child frame determines what eventually happens to certain elements on the parent page when the server returns the results to the child frame. I've tested everything, and it all works fine, except for one noticeable glitch.  If someone happens to call a function on the main page that tries to read an element inside of a div container while the child frame is making a change to any element inside the same div container, the program gives a null error. When I check the elements of the div container with the debugger, all of the elements (14 in total) inside that specific div container are gone. I'm sure I can solve the problem by querying a random element first to see if it exists, and if not, put a call back function a second later once the child frame finishes with the parent page. But I'm curious as to why all elements inside that specific div container are gone at that exact moment in the first place, since the child frame only manipulates 5 of the elements inside that div, and the parent request is looking for a completely different element that is not being manipulated by the child frame. Am I correct to assume that making changes to an element inside of a div container forces a rewrite of all the elements inside that div? All other div container elements in the body of the document remain intact, just the one div that's being changed. This is not the exact code (too much to post) but an example.

```js
// Parent
document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Where did you go?";

// Child Frame
parent.document.getElementById("pic").src = "anotherpic.jpg";
```

```html
<div id ="something">
  <P id = "heading">blah blah blah</p>
  <img id = "pic" src = "picture.jpg">
  <p id = "picname">Picture Name</p>
</div>
```

If the Child runs first, and the Parent tries to read an element while the child is still making changes to an element inside the div, all elements disappear when I look for them in the debugger. Any insights into this behavior are appreciated. Thanks. (Hopefully, this was not a stupid question. lol)

Comment: Can you post how exactly you are modifying the parent document's div?

Comment: Sorry. It would be impossible for me to post it all. There are 30 divs which are being used as menus, and all exhibit the same behavior. if the parent tries to access an element at the exact same time the child tries to make changes to any element in the same div container, I get a null error, and all elements are gone when I check for them in the debugger. If the Parent accesses them first, or the Child accesses them first, everything runs fine. Just if the event happens at the same time. I'm changing the elements on the Parent from the Child in the exact same way as the example I posted.

Comment: "*I assume that making changes to an element inside of a div container forces a rewrite of all the elements inside that div?*" - that's what `innerHTML` does, and that's why it should be avoided. If you make the changes *inside* the element though, it should not affect the other elements in the container - only if you set the `innerHTML` of the whole container.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. Yes I'm aware innerHTML does that. But it shouldn't effect the other elements in the div that are not being queried. Plus I'm not changing the innerHTML of the div itself. Just 1 element within the div. The problem is all the elements are physically missing, and I'm not using any code that creates or deletes any elements. That's why the Parent is coming up with a null error, because it can't physically find the element anymore. It's strange.

Comment: Then we need a [mcve] to investigate, we can't help you solve a problem without the exact code that produces it

Comment: That's what I was meaning to ask for - just in what way you're modifying the container. Even if this is the `innerHTML` but applied only to particular few child divs - it does not affect the siblings.

I suspected you're creating the set of 30 divs every time (even if effectively only few of them are different) by modifying the parent div `innerHTML`, that would be different, which I see is not the case.

Comment: Also mind this - there's no such thing as "at the same time". Both, the `innerHTML` and `getElementById` work synchronously so I'd look elsewhere to find a reason behind it.

eg. the IFrame content modifies the parent *twice* every time, first of which makes it empty.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktus239. That's exactly what I'm looking for. To understand the behavior. I was wondering if maybe it was behaving in an asynchronous manner. But you've told me it is synchronous. That helps me a lot.

Comment: @Wiktus239 If you would like to post that comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct, since my question is about behavior, and this answers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please mind there is no such thing as "at the same time" here. Both, the `innerHTML` and `getElementById` work synchronously.

Even if you used the `innerHTML` improperly (which I know isn't the case) eg. overriding the parent component - there's no "in-between state" that you'd be able to access with the functions, to notice that there are no elements for a "moment". So I'd look elsewhere to find a reason behind it.

eg. the Iframe content modifies the parent twice every time, first of which makes it empty.

Comment: Thanks. I thought maybe there was an asynchronous event happening between the two scripts. This helps a lot in understanding how it's behaving, and what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:
target.addEventListener(type, listener [, options]);

Instead of:
getElementById
?

Looks like something is getting overwritten.

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer